# How to set username and password in PHP script for Salesforce login using Rest API

Tags: php, rest, oauth, salesforce, salesforce-communities

I'm trying to login to my Salesforce Account and retrieve some data. So far i have been able to login to Salesforce by providing the username and the password on the Salesforce login page and then redirecting to the data page which i have some `echo` statements. I want to know how to set the username and password in PHP itself, and make a successful Salesforce login.I used this documentation provided by Salesforce, [Interact with the Force.com REST API from PHP](http://developer.force.com/cookbook/recipe/interact-with-the-forcecom-rest-api-from-php)

Please help.

Following is my `config.php`

```
<?php

    ini_set('display_errors',1);
    error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_WARNING); 

    define("CLIENT_ID", "xxx");
    define("CLIENT_SECRET", "xxx");
    define("REDIRECT_URI", "https://xxxx/oauth_callback.php");
    define("LOGIN_URI", "https://login.salesforce.com");

    define("USERNAME","xxxx@xxx.com");
    define("PASSWORD","*******");
    define("SECURITY_TOKEN","xxxx");

?>
```

Following is my `oauth.php`

```
<?php
require_once 'config.php';

$auth_url = LOGIN_URI
        . "/services/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id="
        . CLIENT_ID . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode(REDIRECT_URI);

header('Location: ' . $auth_url);
?>
```

Following is my `oauth_callback.php`

```
<?php
require_once 'config.php';

session_start();

$token_url = LOGIN_URI . "/services/oauth2/token";

$code = $_GET['code'];

if (!isset($code) || $code == "") {
    die("Error - code parameter missing from request!");
}

$params = "code=" . $code
    . "&grant_type=authorization_code"
    . "&client_id=" . CLIENT_ID
    . "&client_secret=" . CLIENT_SECRET
    . "&username=" . USERNAME
    . "&password=" . PASSWORD
    . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode(REDIRECT_URI);

$curl = curl_init($token_url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $params);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CAINFO, dirname(__FILE__) . '/cacert.pem');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);


$json_response = curl_exec($curl);

$status = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

if ( $status != 200 ) {
    die("Error: call to token URL $token_url failed with status $status, response $json_response curl_error " . curl_error($curl) . " curl_errno " . curl_errno($curl));
}

curl_close($curl);

$response = json_decode($json_response, true);

$access_token = $response['access_token'];
$instance_url = $response['instance_url'];

if (!isset($access_token) || $access_token == "") {
    die("Error - access token missing from response!");
}

if (!isset($instance_url) || $instance_url == "") {
    die("Error - instance URL missing from response!");
}

$_SESSION['access_token'] = $access_token;
$_SESSION['instance_url'] = $instance_url;

header( 'Location: demo_rest.php' ) ;
?>
```

Following is my `demo_rest.php` (shows the output)

```
$query = "SELECT Id FROM test__c limit 3";

$url = "$instance_url/services/data/v20.0/query?q=" . urlencode($query);

$curl = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,
        array("Authorization: OAuth $access_token"));
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CAINFO, dirname(__FILE__) . '/cacert.pem');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);

$json_response = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);

$response = json_decode($json_response, true);

$total_size = $response['totalSize'];

echo "$total_size record(s) returned<br/><br/>";

echo "<br/>";

print_r($json_response);
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem is you can not get the values of variables $instance_id and $access_token on your demo_rest.php file.

Replace the code of your demo_rest.php file with the one below.

```
<?php
session_start();

$access_token = $_SESSION['access_token'];
$instance_url = $_SESSION['instance_url'];

$query = "SELECT Id FROM test__c limit 3";

$url = "$instance_url/services/data/v20.0/query?q=" . urlencode($query);

$curl = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,
        array("Authorization: OAuth $access_token"));
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CAINFO, dirname(__FILE__) . '/cacert.pem');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);

$json_response = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);

$response = json_decode($json_response, true);

$total_size = $response['totalSize'];

echo "$total_size record(s) returned<br/><br/>";

echo "<br/>";

print_r($json_response);
?>
```

If it doesn't work, just leave me a comment.

Comment: @Ozgur The thing is my code is working. The issue is, I manually have to provide the username and password through the Salesforce Login Page. I want to set the username and password from the PHP Script itself and without redirecting to the Salesforce login page, output the data. 
But when i try your code, still it redirects to the salesforce login page!

Comment: @NisalMalindaLivera you might want to have a look at following link, or similar docs -> https://labs.hybris.com/2012/06/18/trying-out-oauth2-via-curl/